# Iterative Guidance Mode (Saturn V ascent guidance)

Tags: saturn-v, guidance

I tried to implement the iterative guidance mode algorithm given in the paper "Development of the iterative guidance mode with its application to various vehicles and missions" by D. C. CHANDLER and I. E. SMITH (https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/abs/10.2514/3.28985?journalCode=jsr) in MATLAB/SIMULINK. I modified the equations for the last stage of SLV only. But I'm not getting the desired results. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. Is there any other report or document where I can find the iterative guidance algorithm except for Saturn V ascent guidance report. I wasn't able to correctly implement that as well.

Comment: Have you found the right result? I have the same problem.

Comment: Yes I found the solution.